# Sitecore/Glass Mapper: how to return query in order of content tree

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

We have a site with several queries that query the direct children of a content item. We simply want just the children sorted by the order they appear in the content tree.

We're using Glass Mapper and our collection properties look like this:

```csharp
[SitecoreQuery("/sitecore/content/Global/Team Members/Categories/*")]
public IEnumerable<ICategory> Categories { get; set; }
```

The above property Categories returns the child items in what seems to be alpha order, but in some cases it seems a bit random.

Any idea how to set up the query to pull in the order of the content tree?

Comment: Glass doesn't use fast query by default. I am not sure why this would behave this way. Have you compared the returned results by Glass against the returned results from the Sitecore API?

Answer (score 6):

Scott,

I believe that Glass is using fast query for these SitecoreQueries which is why you aren't getting any predictable sort order.  Unfortunately the fast query does not allow sorting in the query syntax.  You will see the same if you put your query into the XPath Builder in Sitecore's Developer Center by using this syntax:

```
fast:/sitecore/content/Global/Team Members/Categories/*
```

I think the quickest way to resolve this is to just add Sitecore's __Sortorder field to your ICategory definition.

```
[SitecoreField("__Sortorder"),]
string Sortorder { get; set; }
```

You could then add another property to your model that returns the sorted version of this.

```
public IEnumerable<ICategory> SortedCategories { get { return Categories.OrderBy(s=>s.Sortorder); } }
```

Keep in mind you can also use the [SitecoreChildren] decorator to get the children of the current item.  I'm not sure if that is actually what you are after, but that decorator will actually return your items in the correct order per Sitecore's SortOrder.